# Python function --- to insert a value at start and end of linked-list --- is not modifying the linkedlist

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

[This is the question I'm stuck at!](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/linked-list-insertion/1#)

The problem is the code is not generating any output. (it doesn't print anything.)

My guess is the `LinkedList` is not getting modified at all!

I have only defined the two functions `insertAtBeginning(head,x)` and `insertAtEnd(head,x)`. The rest of the code is from GeeksForGeeks.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

# function inserts data x in front of list and returns new head 
def insertAtBegining(head,x):
    # code here
    global a
    if head is None:
        a.head = Node(x)
        # head.next = None
    else:
        node = Node(x)
        node.next = a.head
        a.head = node
        # head.next = node
        
    
# function appends data x at the end of list and returns new head
def insertAtEnd(head,x):
    # code here
    global a
    if head is None:
        a.head = Node(x)
        # head.next = None
    else:
        node = Node(x)
        current = head
        while current.next is not None:
            current = current.next
            
        current.next = node
        # node.next = None

#{ 
#  Driver Code Starts
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None

def printList(head):
    while head:
        print(head.data,end=' ')
        head=head.next
    print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t=int(input())
    for cases in range(t):
        n=int(input())
        a=LinkedList()
        
        nodes_info=list(map(int,input().split()))
        for i in range(0,len(nodes_info)-1,2):
            if(nodes_info[i+1]==0):
                a.head = insertAtBegining(a.head,nodes_info[i])
            else:
                a.head = insertAtEnd(a.head,nodes_info[i])
        printList(a.head)

 
# } Driver Code Ends
```

I hope I have provided all the necessary information. Please help.

Comment: I can't define methods for the class there. The task is to write the two functions to modify the linkedlist. Check the if-else block where the two functions are being called.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad! Editing it right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `insertAtBegining` is expected to return the new head of the linked list, whereas your implementation doesn't look like it returns anything at all.